# Error if try build app on apple silicon, m1

Tags: swift, xcode, apple-m1, arm64, apple-silicon

have problem with my project when trying to build my app on M1 Pro Mac. If I want to build it on simulator, It's works when I added arm64 x86-64 to Excluded arch in build settings to Debug. But sometimes I need to build app on my device iPhone. And it works only if I delete this strokes in build settings. Could someone help with it? I need some settings to work both on device and simulator without adding/deleting Excluded arch build settings every time when I need it.

Xcode shows errors something like that :
"Could not find module 'Moya' for target 'arm64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: x86_64-apple-ios-simulator" and not only for Moya.

Comment: Switch to using SPM instead of one of the other import options

Comment: @loremipsum how can I solve problem without migrating on SPM? I use cocoapods

Comment: If you Google cocoa pods installation on m1 you’ll find some solutions but cocoa pods is a hassle on m1

Comment: @loremipsum could you please provide link with info?

Comment: https://medium.com/bricksnbrackets/how-to-correctly-install-cocoapods-on-m1-m2-6abe3736c221